# remove # before of orders number in woocommere

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

sign # before of order numbers is a not important thing and adds an unnecessary sign that makes customers confused. for example for tracking orders they have to insert #1234. i want they do not need to add # sign for order tracking and other cases.

[image]

check css codes in this [page](https://gymarket.ir/%D9%BE%DB%8C%DA%AF%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D8%B3%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%AA/)

example for test
traking code(right field): #3444

tracking email (left field): dr_sajjad1369@yahoo.com

plugin: Guest Order Tracking for WooCommerce

Comment: I thought this was going to work, but this appears not to be the case https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-add-prefix-or-suffix-to-woocommerce-order-number/ 
I finally came up with this https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/6518

Comment: i did not found there an answer, is there?